# Implementing a foreign key relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class `Problem` and then various other classes  which extend the base class `Solution` like `BasicSolution`, `ExpertSolution`, many other 
solution sub classes.  The `Problem` class will be a 'foreign key' for the various solutions classes, although the `Problem` class doesn't need the solution list.

So I want foreign key of `Problem` table in various solution tables (one table per solution sub-class). How I can achieve it through Hibernate?

I know that this is not the right DB design from Hibernate's perspective but it's a legacy system and can't be tweaked. I know one-to-many entity 
association but that will need some Solution list to be present in Problem class (which I don't want).

Can you please suggest some answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the relation in the Solution base class with @ManyToOne association:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Solution {
...
    private Problem _problem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PROBLEM_ID")
    public Problem getProblem() {
        return _problem;
    }
...
}
```

All Solution sub classes will have the relation to Problem.

You can also use @OneToOne instead of @ManyToOne, the difference is that @ManyToOne must have the foreign key on this side of the relation.

Comment: A Problem can have multiple solutions, so in solution tables( multiple tables, per table for each type of solution) there will be a foreign key for Problem table.  Now issue is that you are not required to have instances of Solution in Problem class.

Comment: Ok now I understand better, I'm editing the answer for your case, thanks you